# App needs long time to Start with a BlackScreen

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity, oncreate

i have a big Problem, my app needs nearly 3 seconds to start/open. In this 3sec i only see a black screen.
I know some issues for this Black-Screen but they are all not the Problem.

I run the traceview and i see that the onCreate needs more than 2seconds. Than i go deeper and see, that addTab of the TabHost needs more than 2sec.

Is addTab also calls the onCreate of each Activity of each Tab??
I also have a Custom_title_bar, but after removing the custom_title it also needs 2-3sec.

So does anyone of you have an idea what i can do?
I really need the different Activities in each Tab so, remove the Activities and use Views are not possible.

Is it maybe possible to initialise the TabBar in a Thread/AsyncTask and invalidate the MainActivity after it finished?

Thanks alot and greetz
- Mirko

EDIT: Here i added some code snippets, at first what is happened in my onCreate in the MainActivity:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);        

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, A.class);
    setupTab(R.string.tab_a, R.drawable..., intent);
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
    setupTab(R.string.tab_b,  R.drawable..., intent);
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, C.class);
    setupTab(R.string.tab_c,  R.drawable..., intent);
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, D.class);
    setupTab(R.string.tab_d, R.drawable..., intent);
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, E.class);
    setupTab(R.string.tab_e,  R.drawable..., intent);

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

SetupTab:

```
private void setupTab(int labelRes, int iconRes, Intent intent) {
    String tag = (String) getText(labelRes);
    mSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag)
                  .setIndicator(createTabIndicator(this, tag, iconRes))
                  .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mSpec);
}

private View createTabIndicator(Context context, String title, int icon) {
    LinearLayout indicator = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    TextView label = (TextView) indicator.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(title == null) label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else label.setText(title);
    ImageView tabicon = (ImageView) indicator.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    tabicon.setImageResource(icon);

    return indicator;
}
```

I also set a custom theme to my application.
In traceview the method tabhost.addTab() needs more than 2000 msec. Maybe this is why i see the Blackscreen that long.

Did someone know why there are the BlackScreen? I guess that there is no BlackScreen when i opan an normal different app. I know how to change the BlackScreen: setting the android:background in the theme to something different but it will not fix the time issue.

I added a SplashScreen but i also see an black screen when the app starts up (but only some milliseconds). 
The SplashScreen is an Activity with an ImageView and full_screen without title. It starts a thread that waits 2sec and than open the MainActivity and finishing themself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is - but a "solution" to it, could be adding a splash screen. (It's not a real solution, since it just masks the problem rather than fixing the issue.)

Check out [this guide](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) on how to create a splash screen.

Note: You will have to provide some code samples for us to be able tell you how to fix the real problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. For this Project a SplashScreen is a wish and i implemented it yet. Now the BlackScreen appears but only some milliseconds. I am not sure why there is that Blackscreen. I think the custom theme is the reason. I will add some code now

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM:
I figured out, that the problem is the custom_title feature.
The only way for me is to add the splashScreen.

Second way is to create the TopTitleBar by yourself as a View and not as an part of the customizable Application.

I think that are bad news, because the blackscreen makes my app not customizable like android told me :(